# Angular - 'Could not find HammerJS'

Tags: javascript, angular, material-design, hammer.js

I'm working on a simple angular project where I am trying to import Material Design into my project but some of the components aren't working properly and a console warning says:

> **Could not find HammerJS. Certain Angular Material components may not work correctly.**

I have `hammerjs` installed and also `@angular/material`. How do I resolve this issue?

### Sidenote

It may be worth noting that if you have `hammerjs` installed and your components are still not rendering correctly to make sure you are using `angular material` **components** and not html elements with `materialize-css` **classes**.
If you *are* using [`materialize-css`](http://materializecss.com/) instead of [`angular material`](https://github.com/angular/material2), [you will need to add it to your project separately.](http://materializecss.com/getting-started.html)

Answer (score 175, accepted):

In your `package.json` file add this to `dependencies`

> "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",

Or if you want an alternative automatic way just you can type `npm i hammerjs --save` (or `npm i hammerjs@2.0.8 --save` if you want, since `2.0.8` is the latest version nowdays) **in your root project folder** and test then, if the problem still occurring try to delete the `node_modules` folder and reinstall it in the **root project folder also** by running `npm install` which will check the `dependencies` (*where `hammerjs` resides*), `devDependencies` ..., in `package.json` file and install them.

Also in your  `polyfills.ts` (recommended to have a one if you have not)

> import 'hammerjs/hammer';

Thus, it would be found while your angular app is executed since `polyfills.ts` itself is called by import *(in a normal case, else you can check it)* in `main.ts` which is the angular apps' entry point.

Comment: adding the import statement to `polyfills.ts` silences the warning, which is great! 

But the material design components are still not rendering correctly :/

I'll include a screenshot in the question description. Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: about `Material`, do you mean that hover on the **i** ? because i do not see an obvious difference

Comment: I've added that and reinstalled the `node_modules` but no change :/

Comment: no. but I'll be sure to check back once I find a solution.

Comment: Seems I forgot to add the css link to my `index.html` file. whoopsie..
All looks fine now. Cheers for the help!

Comment: I'm not using any of the components that need `hammer`. Is there a way to disable these warnings? I get like 30 of these in my tests.

Comment: what kind of warnings ?

Comment: Why doesn't the library depend directly on 'hammerjs' since its going to use it anyway?

Comment: @Caramiriel not all material components depends on it in fact, so that is why, it would be useless for someone who use only  components that dont require hammerjs.

Comment: import 'hammerjs/hammer'; removed warning for me

Comment: This is a wrong answer. Only works to silence the warning please avoid

Comment: @JimmyKane, it worked for 147 persons (min), thanks for the downvote :)

Comment: of course it works but its not a polyfill so why put it there? 
There is a difference from working and the proper solution right? 
Can you explain why you should put it in polyfills?

Comment: So hammerjs is a polyfill not a library to provide gestures according to you? 
In all documentation etc nowhere so far or even on hammerjs repo its mentioned to be polyfill. Adding that import there implies that later on , when a browser implementes this you can remove hammerjs from there (or if you are not targeting that browser) , which will not happen. Browsers wont provide the same hammerjs api and that is why its needed. 
You can add at polyfill js even your app init but that should not be the case.

Comment: Even searching for hammerjs + polyfill only leads here :-D

Comment: Anyways its not a valid answer for angular. According to the specs and the material team it should be in main.ts as polyfill.js might be gone in the next releases. 

And hammerjs is not a polyfill. 

Its ok to disagree

Answer (score 111):

Install hammerjs

- with **npm**

  ```
  npm install --save hammerjs
  ```
- (or) with **yarn**

  ```
  yarn add hammerjs
  ```

Then import `hammerjs` on your app's entry point (e.g. src/main.ts).

```
import 'hammerjs';
```

Comment: ah good answer, I didn't care to think that this is probably what a lot of people who find this question might want to know

Comment: This should be the right answer. Additionally, you should add `import 'hammerjs';` in every `*.spect.ts` test file that uses material components in order to fix the warning when running `ng test`.

Comment: I didn't need to change the `tsconfig.json` but the import works, thanks for the answer.

Comment: if you have to add the import to every spec file, shouldn't there be a way to add it to the karma.conf file?

Comment: The [cited source](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started) says to `import it on your app's entry point (e.g. src/main.ts)` rather than in app.module.ts. Obviously, it doesn't actually matter anyway though.

Comment: This worked for me with Laravel Vite - TALL stack.

Answer (score 9):

In your `systemjs.config.js` file you also need to add the following entry:

`'hammerjs': 'npm:hammerjs/hammer.js',`

along with of course:

`'@angular/material': 'npm:@angular/material/bundles/material.umd.js',`

The other thing that's missing from your code (at least based on what you have in the GH repo) is the inclusion of the Material Design CSS, add this to your `index.html` file:

`<link href="https://rawgit.com/angular/material2-builds/master/core/theming/prebuilt/indigo-pink.css" rel="stylesheet">`

I hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry to take so long to get back to you. I don't think my project is using systemjs. although you are right about me forgetting to import the css! thank you so much it's now looking right!

Answer (score 8):

this worked for me (and this is with ionic4 as well)
I could make hammer.js work - and also ionic with material.angular.io (in the bottom)

Hammer + ionic (hammer + angular as well):

```
npm install --save hammerjs
npm install --save @types/hammerjs
```

then

```
package.json
make sure in dependencies there is this line
"hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
```

then

```
tsconfig.json - added types as seen below

"compilerOptions": {
...
...
"types": [
"hammerjs"
]
}
```

then

```
in app.component.ts (only there)
import 'hammerjs';
```

then

```
in html file (I just took out the first and last < > signs)
div id="myElement"></div
in .ts file
```

Sample code from hammerjs site works

```
let element2 = document.getElementById('myElement');
let hamming = new Hammer(element2);
hamming.on("panleft panright tap press pressup", function(ev) {
    element2.textContent = ev.type +" gesture detected.";
    console.log(ev.type +" gesture detected.");
});
```

Hammer+ionic+material:
to make material hammer work with ionic

```
in app.module
import { HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { GestureConfig } from '@angular/material';

providers: [
    { provide: HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG, useClass: GestureConfig },
]
```

and voila, your material slider works.

Answer (score 3):

Open your command line or powershell, type the directory of your angular2 project: `cd your-project's-root`, hit enter and paste:

```
npm install hammerjs --save
```

Npm will automatically add all dependencies into your `package.json` file.

Comment: @torazaburo Hammerjs version on npm is being updated frequently so the OP can be sure that if he install hammerjs by using npm command it will be up to date&working.

Comment: @torazaburo To be honest I didn't use `--save` while installing it by npm and everything went smooth, but since you are a very experienced user it would be imprudent to argue with you.

Comment: I think `--save` is no longer necessary because it will be used automatically. https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install

Comment: If you omit the ```--save``` it will still work, but it will not be added to the package.json file, which means that it will not be automatically installed when running ```npm install``` in the future

Answer (score 3):

Install with

```
npm install --save hammerjs
```

or

```
yarn add hammerjs
```

After installing, import it on your app's entry point (e.g. src/main.ts).

```
import 'hammerjs';
```

[Angular Material Getting Started Guide](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started#step-5-gesture-support)

Answer (score 3):

1. npm install hammerjs --save
2. npm install @types/hammerjs --save-dev
3. add this to typescript.config under compiler options

   "types": [
         "hammerjs"
       ]
4. add this to app.components.ts:

[image: hammerjs]

Comment: YOU sir, are a savior and if I ever manage to get a second son, he will be named after you!

Answer (score 3):

Starting from Angular 9 you need to add `HammerModule` to `imports` array of your `AppModule`. Please, find the example below:

```js
...

import {
  BrowserModule,
  TransferState,
  BrowserTransferStateModule,
  HammerModule, // <-- Hammer Module
} from '@angular/platform-browser';

...

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HammerModule, // <-- Hammer Module
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Don't forget to do `npm install` or `yarn add` for adding hammerjs to your project. For a more convenient way, it will be better to install [@types/hammerjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/hammerjs)

Answer (score -1):

Other than importing hammerJS separately,we can provide this gesture recognition feature to yes while installing angular material(version 8) library with the following command.

```
npm add @angular/material

Set up HammerJS for gesture recognition?-Yes
```

Verify the 'hammerjs' is imported into main.ts file

Comment: hammerjs is no longer used by Angular Material.

Comment: specified the version number to avoid confusion

Answer (score -2):

In your package.json file add this to dependencies

"hammerjs": "^2.0.8",

Or if you want an alternative automatic way just you can type npm i hammerjs --save (or npm i hammerjs@2.0.8 --save if you want, since 2.0.8 is the latest version nowdays) in your root project folder and test then, if the problem still occurring try to delete the node_modules folder and reinstall it in the root project folder also by running npm install which will check the dependencies (where hammerjs resides), devDependencies ..., in package.json file and install them.

Comment: Please don't copy or re-post the accepted answer. The accepted answer already mentions the primary steps that you've written as part of your answer.

Comment: This is a copied duplicate answer.