# Angular2: hammerjs is not found

Tags: angular, hammer.js

I'm trying to integrate Angular's material design and I'm the following the [official documentation](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started).
I have installed the compnents and hammerJS using npm:
`npm install --save @angular/material`
`npm install --save hammerjs`
And in my `app.module.ts` I have called the `MaterialModule` and `hammerjs`:

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './comps/header.component';
import 'hammerjs';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, MaterialModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HeaderComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

But the console gives me this error:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/hammerjs 404 (Not Found)
```

What am I missing here ?

Comment: Did you check it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41322566/angular-2-could-not-find-hammerjs/41322790

Comment: @Kinduser yes I did but I don't have the polyfills.ts file (I'm using the last version of angular)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's simply a JS library, you can add it as a script in your index.html file.

You would typically import it if there is a typings for it, but I wouldn't import just a JavaScript file.

Look in your node_modules folder and add something like:

```
<script src="node_modules/hammerjs/... .js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you this did the trick. But why this is not mentioned in the official documentation !! That's really weird.

Comment: I think it's because depending which framework you use there are different ways to add external libraries. This is the easiest way and you can reference specific functions in a component like:

declare var functionName;

I think there are typically better and more recommended ways to add these libraries though; depends on what you are using