# How to add angular material design to jhipster

Tags: jhipster

I am trying to add material desing to jhipster generated gateway. Although it seems it is working I am getting this warning on console;

```
Could not find Angular Material core theme. Most Material components may not work as expected. For more info refer to the theming guide: https://material.angular.io/guide/theming
Could not find HammerJS. Certain Angular Material components may not work correctly.
```

Below lines are added to package.json dependencies

```
"@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.7",
"hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
```

Below lines are added to global.scss

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,400i,500,700');
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';
```

Just note that if I comment out indigo-pink.css line UI becomes uglier so I conclude that this css is imported successfully when not commented.

Jhipster version is  4.5.6

What can be the reason for the warning

Edit 1: this solves the hammerjs warning https://stackoverflow.com/a/41322757/795168 , but still theme warning and problem on UI is continues

Comment: remove the bootsrap package and try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding  angular material to monolothic jhipster project worked for me by deleting hammerjs if it is installed

```
npm uninstall hammerjs --save
```

and verify that is deleted in **package.json** file

Answer (score 0):

Install the @angular/material library and add the dependency to package.json

```
npm install --save @angular/material
```

Import the Angular Material NgModule into your app module...

```
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
  ...
  MaterialModule
 ],
  ...
})
```

Now that the project is set up, it must be configured to include the CSS for a theme. Angular Material ships with some prebuilt theming, which is located in node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/.

To add an angular CSS theme and material icons to your app

```
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';
@import '~https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons';
```

please check with the link [Install Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started)

Comment: I have already did all these steps, do you know jhipster? Question is related to jhipster

Comment: i create jhipster application at least one application. jhipster fully supports angular cli. this works. What is your exact issue?

Comment: adding deeppurple-amber.css directly to index.html solved the warning problem but material widgets are not working as expected.. For example md-menu is not closed once opened

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to add both **@angular/animations** and **@angular/material** with the specific version that is compatible with your angular version.

```
npm install --save-exact @angular/animations@x.x.x
npm install --save-exact @angular/material@x.x.x
```