# Remove HammerJS from a Angular-Material project

Tags: angular, angular-material, hammer.js

I'm working on an Angular application with Material design. Recently I found a memory leak in one of my pages. Every time this page is loaded it takes more and more time to initialize/render.

This page contains a Material table `mat-table` (15 columns x 100 rows) with a Material Tooltip `mat-tooltip` on each cell.
After some research, I understand that the memory leak is due to the Tooltip (and not the table).

A post on Github suggested removing HammerJS as a fix, see: https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/4499.

Now that the memory isn't leaking anymore I'm still getting these 2 warnings:

> Could not find HammerJS. Certain Angular Material components may not work correctly.
>
> Hammer.js is not loaded, can not bind 'longpress' event.

So how to tell Angular-Material I'm not interested in touch-gestures, therefore I'm not interested in HammerJS?

Frameworks versions:

- Angular/ Angular CLI v6.0.1
- Angular-Material v6.4.0
- Node v8.11.1
- TypeScript v2.7.2
- HammerJS - 2.0.8 (before removal)

Comment: Could you provide more info about Angular and Material version used? There is ongoing effort to make HammerJS optional and lazy-loaded

Comment: @TomaszBłachut , Done. P.S if this is a version issue I can update to the latest versions

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old question but to anyone coming here for an answer, I found a solution to this on this GitHub [link](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/14668)

I added this to my `app.module.ts`

```
import { HAMMER_LOADER } from '@angular/platform-browser';

providers: [{
  provide: HAMMER_LOADER,
  useValue: () => new Promise(() => {})
}]
```

As for the unit tests, I added individually to each test class.

**EDIT (Recommended)**

This is the better [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41322757/7113839) to the answer

Install the `hammerjs` module with

> npm install hammerjs --save

Then add the following line to your `polyfills.ts`

```
import 'hammerjs/hammer';
```