# Could not find HammerJS in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular-material, hammer.js

I use angular-material in my project. I am getting this warnings:

> Could not find HammerJS. Certain Angular Material components may
> not work correctly.
>
> The "longpress" event cannot be bound
> because Hammer.JS is not loaded and no custom loader has been
> specified.

I know this is a duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41322566/angular-2-could-not-find-hammerjs)

In the answer they have mentioned that:

1. We have to add `"^2.0.8",` to `dependencies` in **package.json** file.
2. import `'hammerjs/hammer';` in  **polyfills.ts** file.

In my case everything is fine, still I am getting the same warning in
browser console.

Comment: Can you please add some demo/code to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Actually i tried to give stackblitz link. When i tried with stackblitz it's not showing this warnings.

Comment: Add here in comments?

Comment: I have lot components, i am unable to find for which component it is showing this warning.

Comment: Shall i post `package.json` file?

Comment: Execute `npm prune` and `npm i`

Comment: Add `hammerjs` from `node_modules` to `angular.json` and then restart the project

Answer (score 95, accepted):

There are 2 ways to solve this problem:

1. Either include the (*main*) import in your main module's file or `polyfills.ts`:

   ```ts
   import 'hammerjs';
   ```
2. Or include the script from a CDN into your `index.html` file:

   ```html
   <head>
     <!-- ... -->
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hammer.js/2.0.8/hammer.min.js"></script>
     <!-- ... -->
   </head>
   ```

Comment: `import 'hammerjs';` has solved my error thanks a lot for that, Actually previously i have imported **(hammerjs)** in main modules file like `import {} from 'hammerjs';`. Is this wrong??

Comment: @PrashanthGH Nope. Just import the module itself. That syntax won't import anything for use with the project. However, importing the module (probably) imports all modules.

Answer (score 28):

Install with

```
npm install --save hammerjs
```

or

```
yarn add hammerjs
```

After installing, import it on your app's entry point (e.g. src/main.ts).

```
import 'hammerjs';
```

[Angular Material Getting Started Guide](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started#step-5-gesture-support)

Answer (score 18):

with angular6, you can include hammerjs path in node_modules in angular.json file.

[Angular doc](https://angular.io/guide/file-structure#workspace-files) says that the purpose of angular.json file is

> CLI configuration defaults for all projects in the workspace, including configuration options for build, serve, and test tools that the CLI uses, such as TSLint, Karma, and Protractor. For details, see Angular Workspace Configuration.

You can include hammerjs node module path in the script list. see below for an example:

```json
 "projects": {
    "demo": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/demo",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/manifest.json"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/hammerjs/hammer.min.js" <- add path to hammerjs
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
          ....
```

Note that you have to restart ng serve for it to take effect.

Comment: This worked, note it's necessary to stop and restart the project for this file to be picked up.

Answer (score 0):

Project global level addition of hammer js

```
"scripts": [
              "node_modules/hammerjs/hammer.min.js" <- add path to hammerjs
            ]
```

Module level Addition

```
import * as Hammer from 'hammerjs';
```

Answer (score 0):

For newer versions of Angular Material, when you install Material you just need to run

```
ng add @angular/material
```

It will ask you something like this

> Set up HammerJS for gesture recognition?

You should answer "Y" and it will automatically configure HammerJS for you.

Angular Material Installation Guide: https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started#install-angular-material