# Hammerjs with Angular 7 cannot find Hammer

Tags: angular, angular7, hammer.js

I ran the command `npm install --save hammerjs` and also put `import 'hammerjs';` inside my main.ts.

However when I write for instance

```
var test = document.getElementById('test');
var hammer = new Hammer(test);
```

I get the following error "Cannot find name 'Hammer'. Did you mean 'hammer'?"

The auto fill provides me with the following options, but not Hammer.

```
HammerGestureConfig, HammerGesturePlugin, Hammer_Gesture_Config, Hammer_Loader
```

What am I missing? Did I forget to run a command to install something?

Thanks,
Much appreciated.

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41322566/angular-could-not-find-hammerjs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular - 'Could not find HammerJS'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41322566/angular-could-not-find-hammerjs)

Comment: I dont believe its a duplicate, I have ""hammerjs": "^2.0.8"," in my package.json already

Comment: If you import hammerjs it is ready to go, see [this article](https://blog.angularindepth.com/gestures-in-an-angular-application-dde71804c0d0).

Comment: As stated in the original question, I included hammerjs in the main.ts and performing "new Hammer()" throws an error "Cannot find name 'Hammer'"